# How can you make the labels for the \part bold in the exam class?

Tags: exam

I am designing homework sets, and I was able to make the numbered problem labels, such as 1., 2., 3., and so on appear bolded. I used \renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{\thequestion.}}

I have tried doing the same thing for the part labels of (a), (b), and so on, but it is not working. If I use \renewcommand(\partlabel}{\textbf{(\thepart)}}, it does not work. I have also tried asking ChatGPT for solutions, and it does try to use techniques involving \usepackage{titlesec} and defining new commands in genral, but it is not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [exam class](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam) uses `article.cls` and that file defines `thepart`, a different name, `thepartno`, is used here. See pages 39-40 of the package manual.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\partlabel{\textbf{\thepartno}}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{parts}
\part Explain why the package manual is better than ChatGPT.
\part Explain why \texttt{tex.stackexchange.com} is also better than ChatGPT.
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I had no idea there was even a manual or that the exam class uses article.cls. I assume the manual explains those terms too? Also, your questions are funny. Thanks again!